# Rails Production Mode Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, dev-to-production

I am trying to put my rails application into production mode, or at the very least remove the error stacks that rails produces.

This is my current set up

Apache -> Passenger -> Rails App

The application works fine in development mode, but when I change the "RailsEnv" to production in Apache, passenger gives me the error show below.  I have tried restarting Apache

```
Web application could not be started
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
...oster["User_Meta"] = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"User_M...
...                               ^
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...r_Meta"] = {"__type":"Pointer","className":"User_Meta","obje...
...                               ^
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
..."__type":"Pointer","className":"User_Meta","objectId":"actua...
...                               ^
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...inter","className":"User_Meta","objectId":"actualObjectIdHer...
...                               ^
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
...ssName":"User_Meta","objectId":"actualObjectIdHere"}
...                               ^
/var/vhost/dev/sensori/app/controllers/_roster_controller.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: you should post `controllers/_roster_controller.rb` code

Comment: hi, I actually just deleted that since it is not used.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the catch. I just deleted all the unused controllers, and now it atleast displays the html. The page does not load the css and javascript files though. When I look in the console, they are all 404

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is being run in Ruby 1.8, although your app is written using Ruby 1.9 syntax, and so it fails. Double check whether your PassengerRuby setting is pointing to the Ruby interpreter you want to use.